# How to create a list of tokenized words from dataframe column using spaCy?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy, tokenize

I'm trying to apply `spaCy`s tokenizer on dataframe column to get a new column containing list of tokens.
Assume we have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
details = {
    'Text_id' : [23, 21, 22, 21],
    'Text' : ['All roads lead to Rome', 
              'All work and no play makes Jack a dull buy', 
              'Any port in a storm', 
              'Avoid a questioner, for he is also a tattler'],
}
  
# creating a Dataframe object 
example_df = pd.DataFrame(details)
```

The code below aims to tokenize `Text` column:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

example_df["tokens"] = example_df["Text"].apply(lambda x: nlp.tokenizer(x))

example_df
```

The results looks like:

[image]

Now, we have a new column `tokens`, which returns `doc` object for each sentence.

How could we change the code to get a **python list of tokenized words**?

I've tried the following line:

```
example_df["tokens"] = example_df["Text"].apply(token.text for token in (lambda x: nlp.tokenizer(x)))
```

but I have the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/3712416053.py in <module>
     14 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
     15 
---> 16 example_df["tokens"] = example_df["Text"].apply(token.text for token in (lambda x: nlp.tokenizer(x)))
     17 
     18 example_df

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**: I have a solution, but I still have another problem. I want to count words using built-in class `Counter`, which takes a list as input and can be incrementally updated with a list of tokens of other document using `update` function. The below code should returns the number of occurences for each word in dataframe:

```
from collections import Counter
# instantiate counter object
counter_df = Counter()

# call update function of the counter object in update the counts
example_df["tokens"].map(counter_df.update)
```

However, the output is:

```
0    None
1    None
2    None
3    None
Name: tokens, dtype: object
```

The expected output must be like:

```
Counter({'All': 2, 'roads': 1, 'lead': 1, 'to': 1, 'Rome': 1, 'work': 1, 'and': 1, 'no': 1, 'play': 1, 'makes': 1, 'a': 4, 'dull':1, 'buy':1, 'Any':1, 'port':1, 'in': 1, 'storm':1, 'Avoid':1, 'questioner':1, ',':1, 'for':1, 'he':1})
```

Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
example_df["tokens"] = example_df["Text"].apply(lambda x: [t.text for t in nlp.tokenizer(x)])
```

See the Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
details = {
    'Text_id' : [23, 21, 22, 21],
    'Text' : ['All roads lead to Rome', 
              'All work and no play makes Jack a dull buy', 
              'Any port in a storm', 
              'Avoid a questioner, for he is also a tattler'],
}
  
# creating a Dataframe object 
example_df = pd.DataFrame(details)
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

example_df["tokens"] = example_df["Text"].apply(lambda x: [t.text for t in nlp.tokenizer(x)])

print(example_df.to_string())
```

Output:

```py
   Text_id                                          Text                                                    tokens
0       23                        All roads lead to Rome                              [All, roads, lead, to, Rome]
1       21    All work and no play makes Jack a dull buy     [All, work, and, no, play, makes, Jack, a, dull, buy]
2       22                           Any port in a storm                                 [Any, port, in, a, storm]
3       21  Avoid a questioner, for he is also a tattler  [Avoid, a, questioner, ,, for, he, is, also, a, tattler]
```

Comment: Please check out the update for my question. I think we still have a little problem here since the elements of the list are may not be strings?

Comment: @AliF I guess you want `token_list = [word for record in example_df['tokens'].to_list() for word in record]` and then you can get the results with `Counter(token_list)`. Add `print(Counter(token_list))` and see if it is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
example_df["tokens"] = example_df["Text"].apply(lambda x : [token.text for token in nlp.tokenizer(x)])
```

which gives us

[image]

As discussed in comments OP needs the frequency of every word in the list.

```
counter_df = Counter()
def exfunc(row):
  counter_df.update(row)
_ = example_df["tokens"].apply(exfunc)
```

which gives the expected output

```
Counter({',': 1,
         'All': 2,
         'Any': 1,
         'Avoid': 1,
         'Jack': 1,
         'Rome': 1,
         'a': 4,
         'also': 1,
         'and': 1,
         'buy': 1,
         'dull': 1,
         'for': 1,
         'he': 1,
         'in': 1,
         'is': 1,
         'lead': 1,
         'makes': 1,
         'no': 1,
         'play': 1,
         'port': 1,
         'questioner': 1,
         'roads': 1,
         'storm': 1,
         'tattler': 1,
         'to': 1,
         'work': 1})
```

Comment: `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Comment: I think we still have a little problem here since the elements of the list are not strings?

Comment: Element of the lists are indeed string

Comment: it is string, check this out `['All', 'roads', 'lead', 'to', 'Rome']` which is obtained as `example_df["tokens"].iloc[0]`

Comment: Please check out the update of my question.

Comment: What do you want the expected output to be, I think you are confusing about the working of `Counter`

Comment: `Counter({'All': 2, 'roads': 1, 'lead': 1, 'to': 1, 'Rome': 1, 'work': 1, 'and': 1, 'no': 1, 'play': 1, 'makes': 1, 'a': 4, 'dull':1, 'buy':1, 'Any':1, 'port':1, 'in': 1, 'storm':1, 'Avoid':1, 'questioner':1, ',':1, 'for':1, 'he':1})`

Comment: @AliF can you try my updated answer and confirm if the solution works for you

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks a million!, I found another solution using `map` as follows `_ = example_df["tokens"].map(counter_df.update)`